How to change a module name defined in version catalog?
I am currently working on a Gradle project, the module I'm using has different versions for specific dependency. How can I append the name of module to include the said version?
This is what I'm working with:
[versions]
minecraft = "1.20.1"
geckolib = "4.4.4"

[libraries]
geckolib = { group = "software.bernie.geckolib", name = "geckolib-fabric", version.ref = "geckolib" }

The module I'm trying to use is actually geckolib-fabric-1.20.1 however, I cannot figure out on how to append -1.20.1 into the name.
I tried to do this:
modImplementation(libs.geckolib) {
    artifact {
        name = "$name-${libs.versions.minecraft.get()}"
    }
}

However, Gradle would search for the module
"...mavenUrl/software/bernie/geckolib/geckolib-fabric/..." instead of
"...mavenUrl/software/bernie/geckolib/geckolib-fabric-1.20.1/...",
which doesn't resolve the one I'm trying to use.

Why do you not simply fix your version catalog file?

@Vampire For modularity, as changing minecraft version would require changing the geckolib module name too.

Yes, it would. That's how it is when you have artifacts with versions in the name. Never a good idea. :-) Maybe you can use the settings script API to define the version catalog, or a second version catalog where this is calculated instead of having it in the TOML. The settings script API is made for cases where calculations need be done and similar.

Alternatievely, to do it in the build script as you asked to, you could probably leverage dependency substitution to replace the dependency accordingly.
